# Create GCP project without organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I have a G Suite account. GCP created an organization automatically when I logged-in with the G Suite super admin. When I'm trying to create a project in the console, the organization is automatically chosen, even when I'm trying to choose 'No organization'.

Is there a way to create a project in the GCP console that is not under the organization?

Thanks

Comment: Use a private account instead of the G Suite one for private (i.e no organization project)

Comment: I can also use AWS :) Why GCP, G Suite, Google Groups and Gmail are tied together? I have a mail account and a cloud account. I don't want to mix them. All I want is to use my mail account to login.

Comment: G Suite is a business solution, not a private/personal one... Your use case is not the typical one.

Comment: That's just your personal unofficial opinion.

Comment: Dan is correct. [GSuite](https://gsuite.google.com) is designed as a business solution; although there are users who basically have one-person companies who would use GSuite.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Organization docs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations):

> Once an Organization resource is created for a domain, all GCP projects created by members of the account domain will by default belong to the Organization resource.

To get an organizationless project, create it with an external account and give ownership to your <s>G Suite</s> Google Workspace account. Then remove the original owner account, and you'll have a project outside of your org.

Comment: Creating projecs with externla accounts seems no longer possible. It seems creating project *requires* an organisation to be chosen and fails otherwise.

Comment: @Kris I just created an organizationless project, so this limitation seems isolated to you.

Comment: You are right Jofre a project can always be created, but the Google Cloud Platform in this case does not allow you to use any resources for free, e,g. Cloud translation requires a payed account, with an organization. So with a project created without an organization, you only have your project ID/key, there are no permissions to add the service required for Cloud translation. At least.. tonight I did not succeed in using Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 without having to specify a credit card number. Google Cloud has a free $300 entry, but to activate that, Google will need a credit card number.

Comment: I don't think this issue is related to a project being within an organization or not, but rather the fact that you need a billing account, as you mentioned: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup#billing